# How to Create a filter search combining two or more numeric strings in a database

Tags: database, filtering

My question is not a about a program code but how to filter any numbers in a database.

I have filter conditions: First Name, Last Name, Age, Birth year, for example. Using Age, I can filter like this:

```
[Age] IN (29,30,41)
```

and filter will result with rows where column `Age` is equal to one of these: `29`, `30`, `41`.

But how to filter if I want the results as all ages having the first digit 2, 3 or 5 (expected results are 20, 21 ... 29, 30 ... etc). I need a short filter for these, so that it could fit in search windows nicely.

The search window only accepts condition separators and keywords: `AND OR [ ] NOT LIKE < > <= >= =`. Although I can filter as `[AGE] LIKE ‘2%’ OR  [AGE] LIKE ‘3%’ OR  [AGE] LIKE ‘4%’` but this is too long to fit in a search window, as mentioned above.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to answer your question without proper knowledge of the exact language behind the search window. Mainly because different languages implement `LIKE` clause search differently.

In **PostrgreSQL** or **MySQL** for example, the language implements `LIKE` clause as pattern search using wildcards. That means, you really cannot put `OR` condition into the pattern itself, like you would do in a [regexp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for example. In wildcards you can only filter fixed patterns.

The closest you can do with it would be

```
[AGE] NOT LIKE '_'
```

which is pretty tricky.

If you are satisfied with ages `10, 11, ..., 19`, too. You will receive all 10, 11, 12, ... as results.

Explanation:

- `_` character defines the length of the pattern, so in this case one (Ages: 1, 2, 3, ..., 9)
- `NOT LIKE` in most SQL returns only records where pattern wasn't found inside the value, so in this case it returns all that is more than one character :)

If, for some reason, `10, 11, ..., 19` are not accepted, you can still make your query short, but a little bit longer, if it fits the search window:

```
[AGE] NOT LIKE '_' AND [AGE] NOT LIKE '1_'
```